# How to see all windows of an application within a space?

Tags: macos, spaces, window-manager, mission-control, expose

I am a fan of the exposé feature in Mac. I work in multiple spaces dedicated to each for respective projects.

However, I would want to see all windows belonging to a particular application on that Space alone. Is there a way I can enable such a thing?

How to see all windows of an application in the same space alone ?

Edit: Added image to display windows of an application which belong to different spaces but shown together:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apple doesn’t design finder and expose to do this. It’s a design decision, so they might add a switch if enough people convince them it’s worth coding, but in the mean time, programmers have utilities to help.

- [Front and Center](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/front-and-center/id1493996622?mt=12) app on the Mac App Store

Here’s a very in-depth write up of how this used to be the default and now is not, if you’re into the history of user interface choices or just want to know a little more about the author(s) of the tool.

- https://daringfireball.net/2020/01/front_and_center

Also, this tool doesn’t show you fake proxy windows on the space, it surfaces the actual windows. If you need something to re-arrange the windows, look to Moom or Divvy - they are long time, super excellent and powerful window management applications to super charge your control and automate window placement in a way that Mission Control (exposé) does.

- https://manytricks.com/moom/
- https://mizage.com/divvy/

Answer (score -1):

**In case you have a trackpad:**

Make sure you have the App Exposé setting switched on in your trackpad settings. Follow the animated example. 
Hover a dock icon of a particular app to show its windows, or simply hover a window of an app to set it for the Exposé gesture.

[image: A Screenshot showing the macOS Trackpad settings]

**In case you don't have a trackpad:**

Still, you may click on a dock icon and click "Show All Windows".

Comment: Would it give all windows: grouped by spaces?